# Setup free shipping for customer group wise in magento2 CE

Tags: magento-2.1, customer-group, free-shipping

How to Setup free shipping for customer group wise in magento2 community edition 2.1.0

I have created a "Cart Price Rule", where i have specified "Customer Group" only **Retailer** and in the conditions if **cart subtotal** greaterthan 100, and Actions section Apply to **"Percent of product Price discount"** and set **"Apply to Shipping Amount"** to yes.

When test in the front end free shipping is applying to all customers, but i'm looking only for "Retailer" Customer Group.

Please let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: enable "free shipping" in configuration will not be an option to allow free shipping to specific customer group only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working fine in mine case. I have created simple shopping cart rule with test and restrict this rule to only `retailer customer` with free shipping.

Please check below screenshot

[image: First Image]

---

[image: Second Image]

---

[image: Third Image]

---

### Retailer Customer on Frontend

[image: Result 1]

---

### General Customer on frontend

[image: Result 2]

Comment: Hi, please check that Retail customer **order total is zero**

Comment: Because I have set discount $100  and test product price is $45, that's why it shows 0 . But please check it shipping price is 0 which is your requirenment  :) @prasadmaganti

Comment: Have you set "Free shipping" in the configuration. I have set your suggestions but its not working for me. Can you change "Apply" field and check

Comment: shipping price will automatic zero If my shopping cart condition match. it is not necessary to enable free shipping for that. As you can see that in retailer customer has zero price but shipping method is Flat rate while In same product and general customer shipping price is $5 in same shipping method(Flat rate) @prasadmaganti

Comment: Okay. I have enabled table rate, fixed rate and ups. After setup for general customer i'm getting table rate $0, fixed rate $0 and ups rates which are not zero. And same as retailer customer. Where i went wrong?

Comment: I am not sure, what you have done in your configuration. But to setup free shipping I already give enough answer :)

Comment: What is the version you are using in Community Edition?

Comment: I am using 2.1 .

Comment: I got it, i'm working on demo database and where free shipping already set for $50, and i have set for $80. So when my cart total greater $50 i'm getting shipping total zero. But for me getting both Table rate and fixed rate $0. but in your screen shot we have only fixed rate $0. Is there any option to set to show only one rate when free shipping applied?

Comment: This is the different thing so you can ask new question about  it. Also, you can accept this answer If its helps you so it helps other :)

Comment: guide me on how to show only one shipping method when free shipping is applied